# ruby on rails - how can i override Devise recoverable.rb - specifically reset_password_by_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, reset-password

following to my previous question [ruby on rails 4 - devise - send_reset_password_instructions - reset password - Reset password token is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431666/ruby-on-rails-4-devise-send-reset-password-instructions-reset-password-r)

I want to override devise recoverable.rb specifically reset_password_by_token method. The reason is to debug reset password issue.

How can I do it ?

I tried to create app/models/recoverable.rb and put in the code like this:

```
class Recoverable < Devise:: Models

    def reset_password_by_token(attributes={})
        puts "reset_password_by_token test"
        super
    end 

end
```

there is no print into the console after reset password.
I am using gem 'rails', '4.2.4'

How do I override reset_password_by_token method

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your monkey patch in the **exact** same namespace :

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module Recoverable
      module ClassMethods
        def reset_password_by_token(attributes={})
          ...
          super
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/f39c6fd92774cb66f96f546d8d5e8281542b4e78/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb

Comment: how do i know where (path) to put this in the app, if i check where is recoverable.rb for devise gem its located  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.0.0/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb

Comment: You have to look in which modules/class the method you want to overload is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `devise.rb` initializer file, in the `devise.setup` block, try adding below code

```
Devise::Models::Recoverable::ClassMethods.module_eval do
    def reset_password_by_token(attributes={})
       debugger
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add it as a class function to whichever modal is used as the devise resource (ei. User):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :recoverable

  def self.reset_password_by_token(attributes={})
    # custom code...
    super
  end
end
```